# Massless QED modified Lagrangian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-electrodynamics, fermions, spinors

Consider a massless theory of QED, with Lagrangian
$$\mathcal{L}_{QED}=
-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+\bar{\Psi}i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\Psi+
e\bar{\Psi}\gamma^{\mu}A_{\mu}\Psi$$

Is there any reason to expect/allow for an additional interaction term of the form
$$\frac{e}{4E}\bar{\Psi}S^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}\Psi$$
turning, thus, my Lagrangian to
$$\mathcal{L}_{QED}\rightarrow\mathcal{L}_{QED}+
\frac{e}{4E}\bar{\Psi}
S^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}\Psi$$

Also, if something like that is not prohibited, what physical phenomenon could it correspond to?

**Note:**
$\Psi(x)$ is the massless fermion field and $A_{\mu}(x)$ denotes the photon field, whereas $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}$ is the usual electromagnetic field strength. $S^{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{4}[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]$ is the spin operator and $E$ is some energy scale so that the additional Lagrangian term has consistent units of mass.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your added term does not appear to be Lorentz invariant. Is that a problem? Also what is $E$?

Comment: Hi @mikestone. I edited about $E$. Why do you support that it does not appear to be Lorentz invariant? Oh yes, sorry, I see. Is it because of the $\gamma^0$ floating around in the additional term??

Comment: You have an explicit $\gamma^0$ so its not Lorentz invariant. Apart from that, there is no reason to not include it. This term (without the $\gamma^0$) is typically present in SQED theories so its not that crazy to include it.

Comment: Okay @Prahar, thanks. To clarify, SQED is the supersymmetric QED, right?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: The rephrased question seems more about phenomelogy and I am not equipped to answer it. What I can say (which might be of interest to you, given your previous questions here) is that this term is one of the very few terms that contribute to the subleading soft-photon theorem (see here https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07534). As always, this corrected soft theorem continues to have an asymptotic symmetry interpretation (see my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.03850).

Comment: Hi @Prahar and thank you for the recommendation. I will have a look at the two papers you refer me to. What I am trying currently to understand is why in massless theories of any spin does the spin operator factor out/have the property
$S^{\mu\nu}=\pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\0&0&p^z&-p^y\\0&-p^z&0&p^x\\0&p^y&-p^x&0}$
(see Choi and Akhoury paper on subleading soft dressings in QED). I am trying to see how I can define such spin operator in massless QED and how it rises in amplitudes (it normally should rise, because of the subleading soft photon theorem).

Comment: I mean if I start with regular QED and set the electron mass equal to zero, then I can write down the amplitude for photon emission for any QED process and expand in powers of $k$. The result for the subleading contributions will include, among others, the Spin Operator $S^{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{4}[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]$. But in no way this is Choi's result, However, I find that $S_{\text{op}}^{\mu\nu}=S^{\mu\nu}-\frac{p^{\nu}}{E}S^{\mu 0}-\frac{p^{\mu}}{E}S^{0\nu}$ reduces to Choi's operator. So I am trying to figure out a way to incorporate $S^{\mu\nu}_{\text{op}}$ in the Lagrangian of QED

Comment: I think you are confusing the spin tensors. The spin matrix $S_{\mu\nu}$ that appears in the soft theorem is the spin matrix of the little group representation ($SO(2)$ or $SO(3)$) embedded in $SO(1,3)$. The spin matrix you have defined here is associated to the representation of $SO(1,3)$.

Comment: They are not supposed to incorporated. Representations of the Lorentz group appear in the Lagrangian, but representations of the little group appear in the S-matrix. This is because one-particle states are labelled by little group reps whereas field are labelled by Lorentz group reps.

Comment: Emm okay @Prahar, thanks again. One last question though, just to make sure I understand things. So, you are saying that if I expand an amplitude of photon emission in powers of the photon momentun (in QED) and I collect all the subleading contributions, then the one depending on $S^{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{4}[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]$ is not modified in any way (or extended by some additional "effective" term in the Lagrangian) such that it becomes $S^{\mu\nu}\rightarrow S^{\mu\nu}-S^{\mu 0}\frac{p^{\nu}}{E}-S^{0\nu}\frac{p^{\mu}}{E}$, but rather there is some representation in which

Comment: ... in which $S^{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{4}[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]$ reduces to the operator in the Choi and Akhoury paper, $S^{\mu\nu}=\pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\0&0&p^z&-p^y\\0&-p^z&0&-p^x\\0&p^y&-p^x&0}$, correct? And this is so, because in S-matrix amplitudes, the corresponding wave-function of the fermions can have little group representations, given that they are massless, yes? And another comment: the fact that the spin operator $S^{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{4}[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]$ is not covariant has nothing to do with this property, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148640/discussion-between-prahar-and-schris38).

Comment: It may be useful to comment that this interaction will change the gyromagnetic ratio of $\Psi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the operator you wrote down has mass-dimension $5$, so including it makes your theory non-renormalizable. This is not inherently a problem, this situation is of course very natural when considering Effective Field Theories. In your notation, $E$ plays the role of the heavier scale that you have integrated out (usually the mass of some particle). Note that this procedure will not only produce the operator you wrote, but will produce every single higher dimensional operator consistent with the symmetries of the original system.

In the context of QCD, the operator $\overline{\psi} \sigma_{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu} \psi$ is known as the chromomagnetic operator. I don't know any nice reviews, but [here's a reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.00361) (it also appears in HQET, [for example here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1388)). I don't know what it's called in QED (I would like to know). I think we can write down a contrived example, if we introduce a heavy charged massive scalar:

$$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} + \overline{\psi} (i D_\mu \gamma^\mu ) \psi + \frac{1}{2}\phi^\dagger (D_\mu D^\mu - M^2) \phi + g \overline{\psi} \psi \phi$$

if you integrate out the massive $\phi$ particle, you should obtain the dimension 5-operator in the resulting EFT. $\color{red}{\text{Note that you will also generate a mass term for the fermion $\overline{\psi} \psi$.}}$ To put it another way, the massless-QED lagrangian as a $U(1)$-axial symmetry that is broken by terms like $\overline{\psi} \psi \phi$, and $\overline{\psi} \sigma_{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu} \psi$.

---

As fewfew4 pointed out in comments, it's sometimes called the Pauli term, e.g. [here is a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9903179) explicitly working out its phenomenological consequences in massive QED.

Comment: On-shell, the $\overline{\psi} \sigma_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}\psi$ term is equivalent to the magnetic part of the Gordon decomposition. Thus, we can expect it to induce an additionary correction to the electron's magnetic moment. So I think calling it a "magnetic term" is not a bad thing.

Comment: I've seen this interaction referred to in the literature as a "Pauli term".

Comment: @fewfew4 thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Such a term is not allowed, if we insist that the $U(1)$ axial symmetry should be respected as in the massless QED.

Specifically, the massless QED Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L}_{QED}=
-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+\bar{\Psi}i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\Psi+
e\bar{\Psi}\gamma^{\mu}A_{\mu}\Psi
$$
enjoys the $U(1)$ axial symmetry
$$
\Psi_L \rightarrow e^{\theta i}\Psi_L \\
\Psi_R \rightarrow e^{-\theta i}\Psi_R
$$
because terms like
$$
\bar{\Psi}i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\Psi
$$
and
$$
e\bar{\Psi}\gamma^{\mu}A_{\mu}\Psi
$$
only couple spinors with the SAME chirality.

However,  a term such as
$$
\overline{\Psi} \sigma_{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu} \Psi= \overline{\Psi}_L \sigma_{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu} \Psi_R + \overline{\Psi}_R \sigma_{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu} \Psi_L
$$
couples spinors with the opposite chirality (right-handed to left-handed), hence the $U(1)$ axial symmetry is broken by such a term, just like a mass term
$$
m\overline{\Psi}  \Psi= m\overline{\Psi}_L \Psi_R + m\overline{\Psi}_R  \Psi_L
$$

Therefore, if we insist that the $U(1)$ axial symmetry should be respected as in the original massless QED, then such a term is not allowed.

On the other hand, if we lift the $U(1)$ axial symmetry restriction, then such a term is allowed, see @QCD_IS_GOOD's nice answer for more details.

Comment: Axial symmetry is broken in the quantum theory anyway so it makes no sense to insist on preserving it.

Comment: @Prahar, about your comment let me give you an example: the Peccei–Quinn symmetry is also an anomalous symmetry broken in the quantum theory. However, the axion modelers take pains to construct Lagrangians to preserve the PQ symmetry, which is then broken via the spontaneous symmetry breaking process. You don't think their work is in vain, right? A side note, the quantum anomaly renders the axions pseudo-NG bosons, instead of regular NG bosons.